# trying to extend ruby with win32 programming

Tags: ruby, winapi, mingw

I have some C++ Win32 code that I want to call from Ruby. But the code needs to be set up like this

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
```

otherwise things don't work right when I try creating windows and stuff. I don't know how to do that with a Ruby extension.

What can I do? Is there some routine I can call from `main()` to set up the process so my win32 api calls work right?

**Edit**: (mostly) solved. see my answer.

Comment: What things don't work right?

Comment: I can't seem to get my layered windows to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShowWindow() takes an nShowCmd parameter, where 0 means SW_HIDE, ie to hide the window:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `nShowCmd` parameter to `10` in the various window-related functions.

Now stuff works just fine... I had just given up when fiddling with hInstance wasn't enough to get it to work.

I can't find much info on `nShowCmd` though. Why do windows not work when it's `0`?